# Nodejs/Strongloop: working upstart config example

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart, strongloop

After update strongloop to v2.10 `slc` stops writing logs.
Also I couldn't make the app to start in `production` mode.

*/etc/init/app.conf*

```
#!upstart
description "StrongLoop app"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

env NODE_ENV=production

script
        exec slc run /home/ubuntu/app/ \
                -l /home/ubuntu/app/app.log \
                -p /var/run/app.pid
end script
```

Can anybody check my upstart config or provide another working copy?

Comment: Did this Upstart job work _before_ you upgraded to strongloop@2.10.0?

Comment: Yes it worked fine with previous 2.9.x version. I'll try to revert strongloop  and test it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you were writing the pid to a file so that you can use it to send `SIGUSR2` to the process to trigger log re-opening from logrotate?

Assuming you are using Upstart 1.4+ (Ubuntu 12.04 or newer), then you would be better off letting `slc run` log to its stdout and let Upstart take care of writing it to a file so that log rotation is done for you:

```
#!upstart
description "StrongLoop app"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

# assuming this is /etc/init/app.conf,
# stdout+stderr logged to: /var/log/upstart/app.log
console log

env NODE_ENV=production

exec /usr/local/bin/slc run --cluster=CPUs /home/ubuntu/app
```

The log rotation for "free" is nice, but the biggest benefit to this approach is Upstart can log errors that `slc run` reports even if they are a crash while trying to set up its internal logging, which makes debugging a lot easier.

Aside from what it means to your actual application, the only effect `NODE_ENV` has on `slc run` is to set the default number of cluster workers to the number of detected CPU cores, which literally translates to `--cluster=CPUs`.

Another problem I find is the node/npm path prefix not being in the $PATH as used by Upstart, so I normally put the full paths for executables in my Upstart jobs.

#### Service Installer

You could also try using strong-service-install, which is a module used by `slc pm-install` to install [strong-pm as an OS service](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Installing+Process+Manager+as+a+service):

```
$ npm install -g strong-service-install
$ sudo sl-svc-install --name app --user ubuntu --cwd /home/ubuntu/app -- slc run --cluster=CPUs .
```

**Note the spaces around the `--` before `slc run`**

Comment: Thanks for response! Yes I'm writing pid to /var/run/app.pid. I'll check upstart logs and strong-service-install a few days later.